# Is there a way to revert the entire system to a set point in time?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup

I have a development computer running Ubuntu. I often mess things up and end up reconfiguring everything on the machine the way I like it. I would prefer to be able to revert my system to a set point.

What is the best way to do this?

I would prefer not to use virtualization because of the performance hit.

Comment: Also, if you like to experiment then ZFS and BTRFS are the best filesystems for doing snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could do this with [LVM snapshots](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html).  This might also have a bit of a performance hit, but it shouldn't be nearly as bad as virtualization.  The link is not instructions to do exactly what you want, but it should get you started.